# Dynamic Binding at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Today I was working on a WPF UserControl to display the current value of a few variables. I was wondering if there would be a way to dynamically add a property at runtime,this is my fix model but i want to add `public string grapes{get;set}` property at runtime and a value to that property.
is it possible to do? if yes then how?

```
public class Food
{
    public string Apple { get; set; }
    public string Orange { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: You're doing something really wrong if you wanna do that.
You shouldn't change a model at runtime for any reason really.
Why not make a list of foods?

Comment: Try using [DynamicObject][1] or [ExpandoObject][2].


  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx
  [2]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MichaelThePotato: There could be reasons for having a dynamic object (it could be ViewModel). I have (in very rare cases though) used dynamic objects with UI binding to get better user experience with simplified data persistence

Comment: @Lakshan as I said, there is no absolute right or wrong there. As long as the code is simple and maintainable you can do it.

Comment: @VijayGill - while you do certainly raise a good point, best practices are a thing too, and this most certainly does not (under any normal circumstances anyway) fall under best practices, thus is likely why it's getting smacked with downvotes.

Comment: @user2366842 - the first best practice is always to write clear and maintainable code. If the usage of ExpandoObject + dynamic binding leads to that, so be it. The "best practices" are not laws.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way to achieve this is using a dictionary instead of properties... You can easily add new fruit types at runtime. .net also has support for dynamic types. Have a look at expandoObject https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx